# ¿Como configurar cuenta de correo en Mailer Ruby on Rails 6 API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailer

He generado un proyecto con Ruby on Rails 6 API y he configurado una cuenta de correo y generado un mailer pero no logro que se envie en correo, cabe destacar en que en consola si aparece como enviado

Este es el controlador que envia el mailer al email del usuario indicado

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_user, only: [:edit, :update]
    KEYS = [:password, :password_confirmation].freeze
    def create
      user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
      if user
        user.generate_password_token!
        UserMailer.reset_password(user).deliver_now
      end

      render json: :ok
    end
end
```

Este es el mailer

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def reset_password(user)
    @user = user    
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Reestablecer contraseña' )
  end
end
```

Esta es la vista

Hi <%= @user.full_name %>,

```
You have requested to reset your password.
Please follow this link:
<%= "http://localhost:8080/#/password_resets/#{@user.reset_password_token}" %>
Reset password URL is valid within 24 hours.

Have a nice day!
```

Asi mi archivo config/enviroments/development.rb en el apartado de smtp

```
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
    # Mailer configuration
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "smtp.live.com",
      :port                 => 25,
      :user_name            => "test@test.com", # the email of the account to send emails
      :password             => "****", # the password of the account to send emails
      :authentication       => "plain",
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
    }
```

y finalmente mi app/mailers/application_mailer.rb

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'test@test.com
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

Esta es mi salida en consola pero el email no llega a la cuenta configurada
cabe señalar que **test@test.com** es solo como referencia y la cuenta que he configurado es una cuenta personal

```
> UserMailer#reset_password: processed outbound mail in 5.9ms Delivered
> mail 5ed5d7cd9de79_168444a749c5525b@DESKTOP-6O0OI16.mail (2005.5ms)
> Date: Mon, 01 Jun 2020 23:38:37 -0500 From: test@test.com To:
> test@test.com Message-ID:
> <5ed5d7cd9de79_168444a749c5525b@DESKTOP-111111.mail> Subject:
> =?UTF-8?Q?Reestablecer_contrase=C3=B1a?= Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
> boundary="--==_mimepart_5ed5d7cd9bc5e_168444a749c551dc"; 
> charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
> 
> 
> ----==_mimepart_5ed5d7cd9bc5e_168444a749c551dc Content-Type: text/plain;  charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
> 
> Hi ,
> 
> You have requested to reset your password. Please follow this link:
> http://localhost:8080/#/password_resets/**************** Reset
> password URL is valid within 24 hours.
> 
> Have a nice day!
```

Estoy tratando de configurar una cuenta personal ¿Me podrian orientar sobre como configurar la cuenta?
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tengo cuenta para confirmarlo, pero el `port` creo que debería [ser 587](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13810580/895789).
Lo otro es que el `address` al parecer se ha actualizado y puede que sea [outlook.office365.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-for-outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040) o [smtp-mail.outlook.com](https://getmailspring.com/setup/access-live-com-via-imap-smtp), no se cual pueda ser, pero prueba ambos.
Por último prueba con [mailcatcher](https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher) para revisar localmente si efectivamente está enviando los correos.

Comment: He intentado tanto con mailcatcher y los dns nuevos de hotmail pero aun asi no logro que mande el email ¿alguna idea?

Comment: Me ha funcionado con mailcatcher gracias

Answer (score 0):

He podido recibir el correo electronico por medio de mailcatcher el error lo tenia en:

app/mailers/application_mailer.rb

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'test@test.com'
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

que remplaza por

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'test@local'
  layout 'mailer'
end
```